# Liberty Core is good for Worklight production use?

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

All,

We are trying to set up Worklight server infrastructure in all environments. As we are aware that WL server can be deployed on any of the following servers:
  1. IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core v8.5.5
  2. IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment V8.5
  3. Apache Tomcat server

We would like to see what is the best option to go with? What are the pros and cons going with each server option available above? And also we would see if we can go with Liberty Core for production use but sure if it is recommended for Prod?

Comment: Liberty Core is fully supported for use in production.